# Is there is any way to remove the filter on clicking the button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, magento

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 space-top-left">
    <?php 
        $appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();

        if ($appliedFilters) {
            foreach ($appliedFilters as $item) {
                $b=$item->getLabel(); // Currently selected value
    ?>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><?php echo($b); ?></button> 
    <?php
            }             
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

This is code through which I have made buttons of applied filters within my product page.

Is there a way to put a cross sign for every button made (on which after clicking, the applied filter from the page will be removed)?

All suggestions welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

[Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnlZf.png)

Comment: can you please be more specific?

Comment: In this code i am getting the values of applied filters on a product page (Like if we click on size 24 then it will be displayed as button the top).But now i want to reverse the changes like if i will click on a cross icon along with every button then it will remove the filter.For more info you can check this website http://www.jabong.com/men/clothing/jack-jones/?style=Checked&cmpgp=menchecks

Answer (score 1):

May this code will help you.

```
<?php if ($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
    <div class="actions"><a href="<?php echo $this->getClearUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Clear All') ?></a></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```